# Terminate other runig apps with windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

I want to terminate other running apps with windows store app(c#,XAML) using timer. I have no idea how I can do this. Any body can help me?

Comment: This question appears to be a request for code

Answer (score 1):

Todays "apps" are all run in a sandboxed mode. This means that they cannot interfere with each other except through pre-defined channels. You will not be able to forcefully kill another app.

Of you want to read more I would suggest this: 
http://labs.sogeti.com/windows-store-apps-live-sandbox/